# Access: Populate listbox only with one item corresponding to that row

Tags: ms-access, listbox

I have a MS-Access form with a listbox bound to a table. The two columns in the table are "Author name" and "Books". I have a textfield that displays the author's name and a listbox which is supposed to list the books corresponding to that author. But when I execute, the books of all the authors are getting displayed for each author.

What should I do to display the books belonging only to a particular author?Can I make any query for this?

```
Author                        Book
 aaa                          Book1
 aaa                          Book2
 bbb                          Book3
 ccc                          Book4
```

The above is the sample table structure. For the textbox with author 'aaa', I want a listbox only with his books (i.e.) book1 and book2. But I get all the books displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your textbox is called **myTextBox** and your dropdown list is called **myList** and your form is called **myForm** and your table is called **myTable**

Go to the design view of myForm. Right click on myList, go to property sheet, go to tab 'Data', go to 'Dataset source' (should be called something similar....I use Access in German). Go to SQL view of the query which is the source of myList. The statement would look something like this:

```
SELECT Authorname, Books
FROM myTable
WHERE Authorname = [Forms]![myForm]![myTextBox];
```

Make sure that the bound column (also under the tab 'Data') is 2

Also make sure that the 'Number of columns' under tab 'Format' is 2 and the 'Column widths' are something like 0;5cm

Then right click on myTextBox, go to propert sheet, under tab 'Event', click on AfterUpdate, choose VBA Code. The VBA Code should look like this:

```
Private Sub myTextBox_AfterUpdate()
Me.myList = Null
Me.myList.Requery
End Sub
```

This should work but I do not claim that this is the most efficient solution possible

Comment: Thanks a lot. I still have a small problem after following your procedure. All the listboxes carry the same value now (i.e.) 'Book1' from my example above. How can I have different values for different listboxes?

Comment: Well in that case you should have two listboxes (one for author and one for books). That is all you need on your form. The user first selects an author 'aaa' from the first listbox, and the second listbox will get populated with the books written by this author (Book1, Book2). Then the user decides to view the books written by another author, so he selects for example 'bbb' from the first listbox and the second listbox gets populated with Book3 only. Simply remove myTextBox and instead add myListAuthors that should have the authors as its source. Add the same VBA to the after_update event

Comment: if you need further help, do not hesitate to ask

Comment: As per the requirements, I am not supposed to have listbox for the field 'author'. I am using a continuous form (Endlosformular). I need to have a vertical display of author's name  and their books side by side. From my example, I would like to have 3 textboxes corresponding to 3 authors and the listboxes for each one of them. But the listboxes does not behave independently.